# Cannot convert from Func<T,T,T> to Func<T,T,T>

Tags: c#, generics, casting, delegates

I'm quite confused by this error:

> `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func<T,T,T> [c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll]' to 'System.Func<T,T,T> [c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll]'  path\to\my\project\Operators.cs`

The types are identical, why is it even trying to do a cast? Here's the code:

```
public static class Operators<T>
{
    private static Func<T,T,T> _add = null;

    public static T Add<T>(T a, T b)
    {
        if (_add == null) {
            var param1Expr = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T));
            var param2Expr = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T));
            var addExpr = Expression.Add(param1Expr, param2Expr);
            var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(addExpr, param1Expr, param2Expr);
            _add = expr.Compile(); // <--- error occurs here
        }
        return _add.Invoke(a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have gotten a warning about this from the compiler. Did you not?

Comment: @EricLippert: There was a warning, but I had them momentarily turned off as I was refactoring a bunch of stuff and I was getting too many warnings about unused variables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that your *method* is generic, introducing a new type parameter `T`. So the `T` outside the method isn't the same as the `T` inside the method.

Just change your method to not be generic:

```
public static T Add(T a, T b)
```

... and it should be fine.

To be clearer, your code is currently *equivalent* to this:

```
public static class Operators<TC>
{
    private static Func<TC, TC, TC> _add = null;

    public static TM Add<TM>(TM a, TM b)
    {
        if (_add == null) {
            var param1Expr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TM));
            var param2Expr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TM));
            var addExpr = Expression.Add(param1Expr, param2Expr);
            var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TM, TM, TM>>
                          (addExpr, param1Expr, param2Expr);
            _add = expr.Compile();
        }
        return _add.Invoke(a, b);
    }
}
```

Note how I've renamed the `T` introduced by the *class* to `TC`, and the `T` introduced by the *method* to `TM`. The error message now looks more reasonable:

```
Test.cs(19,20): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type
        'System.Func<TM,TM,TM>' to 'System.Func<TC,TC,TC>'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `T` for your `Operators<T>` class and the `T` type parameter for `Add` are different types, so there's no guarantee that the types are compatible.

For example you could do:

```
Operators<string>.Add<int>(1, 2);
```

The compiler emits a warning to this effect:

> Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer
>   type 'Operators'

Comment: Well spotted on the warning front. It's always worth checking the warnings first :)

Comment: Hah. I had warnings turned off because it was spamming about variables I declared but haven't used yet :-) Serves me right.