# Generic Type Conflicts?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-safety

I saw [**this interesting question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055900/cannot-convert-from-funct-t-t-to-funct-t-t)  which talks about `T` declaration at the class level and the same letter `T` ( different meaning) at the method level.

So I did a test.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c = new MyClass<int>(); //T is int
            c.MyField = 1;
            c.MyProp = 1;
            c.MyMethod("2");
        }


        public class MyClass<T>
        {
            public T MyField;
            public T MyProp { get; set; }
            public void MyMethod<T>(T k)
            {
            }
        }
```

As [Eric said](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15055900/859154) , the compiler does warn.

But Hey , what happened to type safety ? I assume there is a type safety at the *Method level* but what about the **global** context of the class where `T` already has been declared.

I mean if someone would have asked me  , I would guess there should be an *error* there and *not a warning*.

Why the compiler allows that? ( *I would love to hear a reasonable answer*)

Comment: I believe this is mostly the same as declaring method variable with the same name as already existing class field name - this works but compiler warn you as well

Comment: Could you expand on "But Hey , what happened to type safety ?" ? What type safety violation, if any, are you concerned is happening?

Comment: Change `public void MyMethod<T>(T k)` to `public void MyMethod(T k)` and there should be an error :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. Type safety is preserved here. Behaviour is alike global and local variables. In *MyMethod* type *T* is unambiguous. We can also create and return new instance of *MyClass* as follows:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T MyField;
    public T MyProp { get; set; }
    public MyClass<T> MyMethod<T>(T k)
    {
        return new MyClass<T>();
    }
}
```

The program:

```
static void Main()
{
    var c = new MyClass<int>(); //T is int
    c.MyField = 1;
    c.MyProp = 1;

    var myClass = c.MyMethod("2");
    myClass.MyField = "2";
    myClass.MyField = "4";
}
```

There is no compilation error and it shouldn't be, because type safety is preserved. Program can be compiled. There is no ambiguity.

The warning should be there, because *T* overrides its class level counterpart and there is no simple way in *MyMethod* to obtain that global *T*. It also obscures legibility.

MSDN says about flexibility and good practice in [Generic Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> If you define a generic method that takes the same type parameters as the containing class, the compiler generates warning CS0693 because within the method scope, the argument supplied for the inner T hides the argument supplied for the outer T. If you require the flexibility of calling a generic class method with type arguments other than the ones provided when the class was instantiated, consider providing another identifier for the type parameter of the method.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a type-safety issue. It is only a readability issue - that's why it's just a warning. (Also, T hides the outer T.)

If change MyMethod() to:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T k)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).FullName);
}
```

It'll print out System.String for your sample code, proving that it is getting the correct type.